# Measurements from a picture

Tags: image, measure

I´m trying to recreate my surrounding in Unreal Engine 4.
Sadly I´m a total loser when it comes to math.
I took a picture of a building.
I know that a door in the picture is 183 cm high and 103 cm wide.
Is there a way to calculate the whole length of the building when you know the size of the door?

Or in other words: How do I calculate distances in a picture when I know the measures of one object in the picture?

If you have the answer it would be nice if you described the process to come up with the answer.

Comment: Well, impossible to know without knowing the ratio of the door width to wall width and height to wall height.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have to find a way to get the ratio. I will try Paint.net and draw lines on my picture and somehow figure out the ratio. Thank you @Chemistpp.

Comment: Here's how I solved the problem: I downloaded a plugin to Paint.net, called Measure Selection. That way I could establish that the ratio of the door to the whole building is 1:30 Then it was a piece of cake to measure windows, ground and other things on the building/picture. Neat!